# File.Regex Expression for editing

Tags: regex, csh

i am really a beginner in file.regex so if someone explain me how can i search for this expression.

```
this.label1.Text = "Version      1.1.1.Beta";
```

How will i write this in file.regex regular expression ??

i want to search this through file.regex and then set new value here through tfsbuild. so please help me as i am really freaked out and cannot find my way out.

Comment: give example please what do you want to change in text

Comment: just for an example i wish to change 
this.label1.text = "Version   1.1.1.Beta" 

to 

this.label1.text = "Version      1.1.2.Beta"

Comment: I don't understand why you need use the regex if you can directly change text like you wrote above?

Comment: i need to change this value in the TFS build for deploying to multiple clients. i dont want to make changes each time in source control. so i want to search for this.label1.Text = "Version 1.1.1.Beta" and change this value to 1.1.2.Beta . Do you know how can i write this expression through File.Regex ??

Comment: As I understood you want to display the version of your application for example on the about form if yes and you use the WinForms you can use the standard about box form it will display the current built version of your application. you can extract this info from assembly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace the string `1.1.1.Beta` with string `11.1.2.Beta` in file `file` you could use sed:

```
sed -i file 's/\(this\.label1\.Text = "Version      \)1.1.1.Beta\(";\)/\11.1.2.Beta\2/'
```

Comment: Thanks bmk. it do make sense. but i have to use it like this

<File.RegEx Path="$(BuildDirectory)/Sources/Client/Client/About.Designer.cs"
 RegularExpression="this.label1.Text = (.*?)"
 NewValue="this.label1.Text = Version 1.1.2.Beta"/>
</Target >